# Angular 5, Firestore, OAuth - get auth uid in component

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have following issue

Got AuthService.ts where I authenticate my users with google account. In the same service I'm sending user details to Firestore db, such as uid, email, etc.

Now. In a component I need to get that uid from logged user, so in a constructor I've defined my AuthService and trying to get the uid.

When I go with `this.auth.user.subscribe(user => console.log(user.uid));` It seems to work -> console logging the uid.

But, when I'm trying to assing it to a variable and console log / use the variable it goes with `undefined` error.

Here is the code:

`this.auth.user.subscribe(user => this.userDoc = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`));
    this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
    console.log(this.user);`

What am I doing wrong?

Thats my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument} from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {AuthService} from '../core/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-judge-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './judge-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./judge-dashboard.component.css']
})


export class JudgeDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  // entryDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  // entry: Observable<any>;
  userDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;
  user: Observable<any>;


  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.user.subscribe(user => console.log(user.uid)); //it works

    this.auth.user.subscribe(user => this.userDoc = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`));
    this.user = this.userDoc.valueChanges();
    console.log(this.user); // this one undefined
  }
}
```

And the AuthService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { User } from '../user';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private router: Router) {
    //// Get auth data, then get firestore user document || null
    this.user = this.afAuth.authState
      .switchMap(user => {
        if (user) {
          return this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
        } else {
          return Observable.of(null);
        }
      });
  }
  googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
  }
  private oAuthLogin(provider) {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then((credential) => {
        this.updateUserData(credential.user);
      });
  }
  private updateUserData(user) {
    // Sets user data to firestore on login
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<any> = this.afs.doc(`users/${user.uid}`);

    const data: User = {
      uid: user.uid,
      email: user.email,
      roles: {
        author: true
      },
      displayName: user.displayName || 'someDefaultValue',
      photoURL: user.photoURL
    };

    return userRef.set(data, { merge: true }); // without {merge:true} it will overwrite nor update.
  }
  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }
  ///// Abilities and Roles Authorizations
  ///// Assign roles to an ability method
  canRead(user: User): boolean {
    const allowed = ['admin', 'author', 'judge', 'partner'];
    return this.checkAutorization(user, allowed);
  }


  // determines if user has matching role
  private checkAutorization(user: User, allowedRoles: string[]) {
    if (!user) { return false; }
    for (const role of allowedRoles) {
      if ( user.roles[role] ) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Even if I go like this:

```
uid: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.user.subscribe(user => {
      this.uid = user.uid;
      console.log(user.uid);
    });
    console.log(this.uid);
```

First console log works. Second one gives `"undefined"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's an asynchronous method,
considering this code block:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.user.subscribe(user => {
      this.uid = user.uid;
      console.log(user.uid);
    });
    console.log(this.uid);
}
```

At first, `subscribe` to the user observable  is called,
then the second `console.log(this.uid);` (*where this.uid is still undefined*) is called,
then when the value is pushed into the observable leading to the block inside the suscription callback being called:

```
this.uid = user.uid;
console.log(user.uid);
```

It's all about being async!

Comment: In fact I'm not an expert with asyncs. 
So the variable was assigned and if I want to pass it in the component i just have to use that with async pipe?

Comment: Yep, That's the way, or you can have a set of non async objects in your component and on any pushed values into the observable do whatever you like to do with them! depends on you logic.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try with async pipe. Hope it solves the problem.